# Criar um Array multidimensional no formato de tabela em Java?

Tags: java, array, arraylist, array-multidimensional

Sou iniciante em Java e e tenho duvidas como criar Array Multidimensionais, tenho a tabela abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para criar um Array Multidimensional dessa tabela?

Comment: todas as casas de um array tem de ser do mesmo tipo, logo construir essa informação como um array bidimensional não é grande ideia

Comment: Entendi, mas preciso encontrar, o maior valor da M1 pela Origem conforme o exemplo abaixo. Não sei com arraylist seria mais fácil do que um Array.

SP VIT R$ 300,00
BH CUR R$ 350,00
VIT CUR R$ 450,00

Comment: Ambas não seriam boas, uma vez que partilham o mesmo pormenor de todas as casas serem do mesmo tipo. Melhor seria representar com objetos.

Answer (score 1):

**Inicializando o array multidimensional:**

```
int[][] a = {
      {1, 2, 3}, 
      {4, 5, 6, 9}, 
      {7}, 
};
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]